# Record AVAudioPlayer output using AVAudioRecorder

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder

In my application, I have list of Buttons when i click on one button corresponding music will be played. I want to record the sounds coming while playing the audio using avaudioplayer. But when i start recording while playing sounds nothing is recorded, Is it possible to record the sounds from avaudioplayer.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might like to check-out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731784/problem-in-playing-recording-sound-with-two-different-players/) thread.